Failed - Internal Error when running on ibmq
I tried to apply a series of an inverse QFT on a single qubit depending on a previous measurement, but when a depth of a circuit became longer I encountered an internal error, Failed - Internal Error on a real device. I'm not sure what's causing the error. The code works without the error on AerSimulator.
I attached a reproducer of the error, the error starts to occur with $n \ge 4$ in the code, while it succeeds with $n=2$.
I'm using Qiskit 1.0.2
Any comment would be appreciated!

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
    from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
    from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
        
    hub = "ibm-q"
    group = "open"
    project = "main"
    provider = IBMProvider(instance=f"{hub}/{group}/{project}")
    
    #n = 8# failed
    n = 4# failed
    #n = 2# succeeded
    
    m = 2*n
    qr = QuantumRegister(1)
    cr = ClassicalRegister(2*n)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
    
    def inv_qft_rot(circuit, n, m, q, c):
        if n==0:
            return circuit
        # get theta index for rotation
        l = range(2, m-n+2)
        revl = list(l)[::-1]
    
        control_idx = 0
        n-=1
    
        angle = 0
        # calculate a sum of angles applied 
        for k in revl:
            circuit.p(-pi/2**(k-1), q).c_if(c[control_idx], 1)
            control_idx+=1
        # apply hadamard gate
        circuit.h(q)
    
    for i in range(m):
        qc.h(qr)
        inv_qft_rot(qc, m-i, m, qr, cr)
        qc.measure(qr, cr[i])        
        qc.x(qr).c_if(cr[i],1)
    
    #qc.draw()
    backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_osaka')
    #backend = AerSimulator()
    
    t_qc = transpile(qc, backend)
    job = backend.run(t_qc, dynamic=True)
    result = job.result()

The full error message :
04/11/2024 11:19:05.483 - user_logger - ERROR Failed to execute program: 'Internal Error'


Can you please share the full error message? That could help.

Thanks for your comment. There isn't much info in it but here's the full error message : 04/11/2024 11:19:05.483 - user_logger - ERROR Failed to execute program: 'Internal Error'.

I'm not sure what the cause was, but the error has been resolved with the latest ibm backend(ibm_sherbrooke) and qiskit ver 1.2.0.
